# Request запрос python

Tags: python, request

Как получить страницу с городом "Воронеж", с помощью реквест запроса, не используя куки?

https://kuhnirubica.ru/contacts/

Comment: «не используя куки» — никак, город выбирается именно через куки

Comment: А если использовать куки, как тогда?

Comment: Открываем в браузере мониторинг сети, меняем город, смотрим, какие куки изменились, и запихиваем их в requests как описано в [документации](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#cookies) `requests.get('https://kuhnirubica.ru/contacts/', cookies={'city': 'vrn', 'city_selected': 'correct'})`